# Start-Sleep not working with Azure PowerShell Task in Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

I'm trying to add a sleep command in an Azure Power Shell Task in an Azure Pipeline, like in the screenshot below. But it's not working, what am I doing wrong?

[image: Azure PowerShell]

Comment: How do you know it’s not working? Is there an error? Or just no sleep noticeable? Please try for debugging purpose to add this, to determine it is really not sleeping ‘Get-Date; Start-Sleep -Seconds 5; Get-Date

Comment: No error message, but I have tried to set the time to 3600 seconds (1 hour), but it doesn't sleep any time at all

Comment: Can you try to add task that only do the sleep and show the task execution's log?

Comment: @vernou You comment help me solved my problem as it showed me that the command was working, I had just placed it in the wrong place in the code. Can you post your comment as an answer so I can select it as best answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound like the instruction isn't hit. To check, you can add a task that only do the sleep. Then you will confirm if `Start-Sleep` work or not.